# How to List alphabet characters based on Pi?

Tags: python-3.x

Hello I wanted to create a list of letters randomized using the values of pi.
I'm quite stuck right now. Just want to ask suggestions to work this code out.

```
import re
import string

#I searched values of pi on the web and set it as x. 
#I used this for loop to get a list of pi values with range from 1 to 100k 

pi_list = []
for num in range(0, 10000):
    pi_list.append(x[num])

#I used this method to join the values into one entry of string
#I think setting it to string would help for slicing later.

pi_values = "".join(pi_list)

#reference list to be used later

a = list(string.ascii_lowercase)

#string of pi values

b = pi_values

#empty list I want to put return values

c = []

#This is by far my code right now. 

while len(c) < 27: #27 because alphabet has 27 letters
    x = 2 #This x is for concatenation
    for i in range(len(a)):

#I want to use pi values from b to return numbers to c then I will assign c list numbers later on to
#objects inside the list a.
        
        while int(b[i]) % 27 in c:
            b[i] = int(b[i:i+x])
            x+=1
            i+=1

#The objective here is to concatenate the next pi value if the current one exists in c and set that as
#the new value for i when the object already exists in list c. Then I use modulus 27 for values with 3 
#digits and above. I want the concatenation to continue until it gets a new value that's not in c yet.
        
        else:
            c.append(int(b[i]))
print(c)
```

[Here is a small scale sample of what I want it to do. Only the first 11 letters of the alphabet was used here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qrKMA.jpg)

I want the program to return a set of 27 characters of the alphabet, 1 time for each letter. Just like in the sample in the image.

Right now, it returns these values.

```
['3', '1', '4', '1', '5', '9', '2', '6', '5', '3', '5', '8', '9', '7', '9', '3', '2', '3', '8', '4', '6', '2', '6', '4', '3', '3', '3', '1', '4', '1', '5', '9', '2', '6', '5', '3', '5', '8', '9', '7', '9', '3', '2', '3', '8', '4', '6', '2', '6', '4', '3', '3']
```

It repeats itself after 27 times, it seems. Not sure what to do here. Will be glad for some help.

Answer (score 1):

## Start Small

I recommend you give you program some more structure. Perhaps start by defining some concepts and then building each of them separately:

```
def pi_digits(n):
  """get pi with n n-1 decimal places: pi_digits(3) returns 3.14"""
  # build this function first
  my_num = ...
  return my_num


def digit_to_char(d):
  """convert digit to character: digit_to_char(0) returns 'a'"""
  # build this function next
  my_char = ...
  return my_char


# test both functions
print(pi_digits(10))
print(digit_to_char(2))
```

Ensure this works. Then expand to iteration.

## Iteration

Once you have this, try iterating the digits of Pi:

```
pi_digits = str(pi_digits)

my_output_str = ''

for char_digit in pi_digits:
  if char_digit == '.':
    continue # skip if the character is a decimal point
  print('digit:', digit)
  char = char_digit
  # convert character to numerical digit (int)
  char = int(char)
  # convert numerical digit to alphabetical char
  char = digit_to_char(char)
  my_output_str += char
```

Note: as digits only go from 0-9 but there are 27 alphabetical characters.

Either way, you can wrap the code in another function like `get_ndigit_picode(n)`.

Comment: Just did the functions, don't know how to share them as codes in comments.

Comment: Edit your question! :) simply add your new code below make a new code section with `\`\`\``